# Installed ProFTP on Ubuntu and it is running but cannot login

Tags: ubuntu, ftp, ubuntu-12.04, proftpd

I just spun up a new server on Digital Ocean that I plan to use for Backup files....my client has a website on a Share Hosting server running wordpress and I cannot get them to let me migrate to a better server.  They have a WordPress plugin called Updraft which does daily backups and is able to upload the files to a remote server using FTP, so I got this server setup just for his backup files.

I installed ProFTPd on this ubuntu 12.04 server using the instruction here... https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-proftpd-on-ubuntu-12-04

**Very basic Step 1...**

```
sudo apt-get install proftpd
```

**Step 2 Configure ProFTP.**...

Open up the file:

```
sudo nano /etc/proftpd/proftpd.conf
```

Go ahead and make a few changes:

Change the Server Name to your host name

```
ServerName                      "example.com"
```

Uncomment the line that says Default Root. Doing so will limit users to their home directory.

```
# Use this to jail all users in their homes
 DefaultRoot  ~
```

**Step 3 Access the FTP server.**...

Once you have installed the FTP server and configured it to your liking, you can now access it.

You can reach an FTP server in the browser by typing the domain name into the address bar and logging in with the appropriate ID. Keep in mind, you will only be able to access the user's home directory when connecting to the virtual server.

```
ftp://example.com
```

Alternatively, you can reach the FTP server through the command line by typing:

```
 ftp example.com
```

---

So I did all that and the FTP server is running now however I cannot login as I enter in my root user and the password for my root user on the server and that does not work.

I imagined it would have it's own user/passwords for this FTP but I saw nowehere in the article or anywhere on where or how to set a user/password for the FTP...did I miss something?

I don't even need a webserver. simply an FTP server to login and upload files from another server with!

Comment: Are you authing via PAM? What do the logs show?

Comment: @FrankThornton sorry im illiterate as to what PAM is and even what logs you are referring too...i've never installed an FTP server, other than ones that installed as part of another script, like a control panel which installed FTP and email, DNS, the whole LAMP stack for me and configured it.  I had assumed since all I need is a basic FTP server on this whole server it would be easy but it's turning out to be more difficult than installing a whole LAMP stack so far!

Answer (score 2):

> I cannot login as I enter in my root user and the password for my root user on the server and that does not work.

Root user login to proftpd is disabled by default see [RootLogin](http://www.proftpd.org/docs/directives/linked/config_ref_RootLogin.html)

To enable Root login, update the proftpd.conf to include:

```
RootLogin on
```

Comment: In Bananian OS this is not enough. May need to edit passwd file to add shell for ftp account. No root access though.